# Assiti Shards universe - Are there any examples of crossovers between different "sub-series"?

Tags: alternate-history, assiti-shards, 1632-ring-of-fire

Note for those unfamiliar: "[Assiti Shards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assiti_Shards_series#Ring_of_Fire)" is a universe created by Eric Flint which is designed to serve as a basis for several distinct series of alternate history/fiction books. The most famous/notable of those is the "*1632*"/"*Ring of Fire*" series.

The common concept uniting the different series is the titular "Assiti Shards". To quote from Wikipedia:

> The Assiti Shards work by displacing bits of the world into other times and places, exchanging it with that which was there. These "shards", according to the fictional universe backstory, are waste byproduct of artworks created by the sophisticated and curious alien race known as the Assiti. The various stories involve shards striking the Earth and timeshifting characters into different periods and places.

As a note, the shards themselves play very little role, at least in 1632 series - they merely serve as a brief couple-pages-long explanation/method for setting up the series universe and don't play any subsequent role beyond backstory explanation.

**QUESTION:** Are there any commonalities (e.g. references to common characters, in-book events, etc...) between the different SERIES of books in the Assiti Shards universe, aside from the shard-based time displacement origins of each series?

Note: I personally don't care if the answer contains any spoilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes -

In [TimeSpike](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-757-time-spike.aspx), there are several researchers who are looking into the disappearance of a maximum security prison.  They also mention the past event of a small mining town also going missing (which was hushed up by Powers That Be)

Comment: +1 - now that I have read TimeSpike, I can confirm that this is the correct answer.

Comment: As a minor side note - while the "1632" series pretty much ignored the shards, the TimeSpike series explored the nature of them a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

I have read a significant amount of these books, but have not found any references or connections.  I doubt there are any.

EDIT: The majority of my reading has been of the 1632 series.  Further research into this question (per other answers/edits/comments) have demonstrated that there are, indeed, a few minor references in other *Shards* series.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is no longer correct - see the accepted answer.